# How to hide appended input names when the value is empty

Tags: jquery, serialization, append

Hi all, I have a small script that appends a list of input values along with their names into a textarea. What I'd like to do is hide the field name when the value is `0` or `empty`.

Here's the script:

```
<script>
  function showValues() {
    var fields = $(".content :input").serializeArray();
    $("#contentlist_copy").empty();
    jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field){
      $("#contentlist_copy").append(field.value + " " + field.name + ", ");
    });
  } 
  $("input").change(showValues);
  showValues();     
</script>
```

I know it's an elementary question and I appreciate your help.

Comment: hide the input ... or the fieldname in textarea ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `.val()` method to set the value of a textarea. You can also use the `jQuery.map()` method to put together an array of strings and then join them. If the callback function for the `jQuery.map()` method returns null or undefined, the item is not added to the array.

```
function showValues() {
    var fields = $(".content :input").serializeArray();
    var tokens = jQuery.map(fields, function(field) {
            return (field.value && field.value != '0') ? (field.value + ' ' + field.name) : null;
        });
    $("#contentlist_copy").val(tokens.join(', '));
}
```

UPDATE:

The code above tried to maintain much of your original code, but you really don't need to call `.serializeArray()`. In the comments you asked about using the "title" instead of the "name". The following code does that:

```
function showValues() {
    var tokens = [];
    $('.content :input').each(function() {
        var $input = $(this);
        if (($input.val() != '') && ($input.val() != '0')) {
            tokens.push($input.val() + ' ' + $input.attr('title'));
        }
    });
    $('#contentlist_copy').val(tokens.join(', '));
}
```

Comment: Excellent. This answers my question to @Chuck Norris. Chuck's method is excellent as well, especially if I could hide the commas.

Comment: One last question. Any idea how to grab the title attribute instead ot the name (field.name)? I tried to declare a title var and assign it this.attr('title'), but no luck.

Comment: @TMK - I have updated my answer to show how to get the title.

Comment: Thanks very much for the follow-up. The Serializerray() call was indeed at issue since the only two attributes stored are the name and the value. The form is working now. thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#contentlist_copy").append(field.value + (!field.value || field.value == "0" ? "" : " " + field.name) + ", ");
```

**Update:**

Try this if you want to hide the commas too

```
$("#contentlist_copy").append(field.value + (!field.value || field.value == "0" ? "" : " " + field.name) + (!field.value ? "" : ", "));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. By the same token, How can I hide the comas ", " when the field value or name are empty/hidden? Right now the textarea is loaded with , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  on page load

Comment: Note, that I just fixed your code. It's much better to use John S's answer :) It's more elegant and right in programming perspective :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    var valuePairs = $('.content :input').filter(function() {
        return this.value.length && this.value !== '0';
    }).map(function() {
        return this.value + ' ' + this.name;
    }).get();
    $('#contentlist_copy').val(valuePairs.join(', '));
});
```