# How to display the title attribute of an input field in a Jquery map function

Tags: jquery, append, javascriptserializer

I have the following script that appends a list of input values into a textarea.

```
<script>
   function showValues() {
       var fields = $(".content :input").serializeArray();
       var tokens = jQuery.map(fields, function(field) {
               return (field.value) ? (field.value + ' ' + field.name) : null;
           });
       $("#contentlist_copy").val(tokens.join(', '));
   }
      $("input").change(showValues);
      showValues();     
</script>
```

Instead of displaying the name attribute `field.name` of the returned field, i'd like to display the title attribute. I've tried a few tricks, nothig is giving.

I should point out that this a follow-up question to this topic:[How to hide appended input names when the value is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836404/how-to-hide-appended-input-names-when-the-value-is-empty)

Comment: well, the title attribute isn't stored in serializeArray. you'll have to use `.map` directly on `$(".content :input")`

Comment: Kevin, can you please clarify?

Comment: .serializeArray creates this: `[{name: "theinputname",value:"theinputvalue"}]` as you can see, `title` is not contained within the array.

Comment: Thanks man and you're absolutely right. I was simply wondering where in the $(".content :input") I should add the .map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title attribute isn't stored in `serializeArray`. You'll have to use `.map` directly on `$(".content :input")`

```
function showValues() {
   var tokens = $(".content :input").map(function() {
       return (this.value) ? (this.value + ' ' + this.title) : null;
   }).get();
   $("#contentlist_copy").val(tokens.join(', '));
}
$("input").change(showValues);
showValues();
```

Comment: Thx for the follow-up. Here's the live example with your suggestion. It's not working somehow: http://jsfiddle.net/treigh/zBHzp/

Comment: You forgot to add the content class, and I forgot `.get()`

Comment: Fabulous! It's working like a charm. Thanks a bunch for the great help.